# Different comportement of read

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to understand why this program return different errors when I change the size of the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
int file = open("./test",O_RDWR);
//char buff[204796] = "" ; -> File Descriptor error (no seg fault)
//char buff[100000]=""; -> Seg Fault
char buff[208896]=""; -> Bad Adress (no seg fault)
int i = 0;
while(read(file,buff+i,2048) > 0)
{
i += 2048;
};
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Test is a file with 500000 A :)

When a Bad adress or File descriptor errors occur, I don't know how to exploit this code.

Answer (score 0):

So, bad access and segfaults aren't the same category. Bad access is thrown by the Mach-o system, while segfault is a POSIX signal, hence, segfault ∈ bad access (it can be thrown by other POSIX signals. I would suspect your error is stemming from your file size, and or the OS blocking you from taking that much memory. Look at your memory at the locations in the dump and see what is stored.